# подключение дисплея 800х480 к stm32 без внешней памяти

Tags: c, memory, display, stm32

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь подключить дисплей с разрешением 800х480 по интерфейсу RGB565 к контроллеру stm32f767zit без использования внешней SRAM памяти. Пользуюсь связкой CubeMX и Keil uVision. При инициализации массива памяти:

```
volatile uint32_t RGB565[192000] = {0x00000000};
```

в конечном итоге Keil выдаёт ошибки при компиляции:

```
767\767.axf: Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions with .ANY selector matching main.o(.bss).
767\767.axf: Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions with .ANY selector matching startup_stm32f767xx.o(STACK).
767\767.axf: Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions with .ANY selector matching stm32f7xx_hal.o(.data).
767\767.axf: Error: L6406E: No space in execution regions with .ANY selector matching system_stm32f7xx.o(.data).
767\767.axf: Error: L6407E: Sections of aggregate size 0xbf93c bytes could not fit into .ANY selector(s).
Not enough information to list image symbols.
Not enough information to list the image map.
Finished: 2 information, 0 warning and 5 error messages.
"767\767.axf" - 5 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
```

Размер необходимого буффера, если я не ошибаюсь, 480*800*2=6144000 бит. Насколько мне известно, у данного микроконтроллера есть необходимая память. Можно ли как либо её использовать, и если да, то как?

Comment: Вам нужно 480*800*2/1024=750кб памяти. А у контроллера ее только 512кб. (192000*4/1024 это тоже 750кб)

Comment: Посмотрите как видеопамять огранизована у ZX Spectrum.

Comment: Вам надо обрабатывать изображение по частям, например, interlaced video.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Теперь мне понятно, что без внешней SRAM данную задачу не выполнить. Приобрел микруху (http://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/41C-LV16105C.pdf). В CubeMX в настройках ядра в поле "MPU Region Base Address" установил 0хС0000000. Оттуда, судя по даташиту на мой камешек, начинается 5ый банк FMC. Тем не менее ошибка осталась.